# drawText with two variables and each different font

Tags: python, pyqt, qpainter, qfont

I dont know if its possible to chose different text font for each variable inside the same painter.

```
painter.drawText(80, 290, self.text1.text() + self.text2.text())
```

This is the example: for `text1` want to leave it default as I set in the painter (`boldUnderline`) while `text2` will have (`boldUnderline`) but also I want to change the text font to another one lets say Arial the point is to be different from `text1` because its supposed to be in different language

Here is the full code:

```
underlineItalic = QFont()
underlineItalic.setItalic(True)
underlineItalic.setUnderline(True)

painter = QtGui.QPainter()
painter.setFont(boldUnderline)
painter.drawText(80, 290, self.text1.text() + self.text2.text())
```

Is there any option to do this on this way?
If it can not be this way is there any other way?

Comment: Why not set font and style for the first text, apply `drawText` with the content, then reconfigure the painter with the other font/style settings and draw the other text with the new settings?

Comment: because i want them to be in the same line, i will divide them with "/" but they have to be on the same line because the second text will be the translation of the first text

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To perform this task you can use `QTextDocument`, to set the format we use `QTextCharFormat()` where you must set a font.

```
doc = QTextDocument()
cursor = QTextCursor(doc)

fm = QTextCharFormat()
font = painter.font()
font.setBold(True) 
font.setUnderline(True)
fm.setFont(font) # set QFont

cursor.insertText(text1, fm) # insert text with new format.

# establish new format for example:
# font.setItalic(True) 
# font.setBold(True)

cursor.insertText(text1, fm) 
painter.translate(80, 290)
doc.drawContents(painter)
```

Example:

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    img = QImage(640, 480, QImage.Format_RGB32);
    img.fill(Qt.white);

    text1, text2 ="Stack Overflow".split()
    painter = QPainter(img);

    doc = QTextDocument()
    cursor = QTextCursor(doc)

    fm = QTextCharFormat()
    font = painter.font()
    font.setItalic(True) 
    font.setUnderline(True)
    fm.setFont(font)

    cursor.insertText(text1, fm)

    font.setItalic(True) 
    font.setBold(True)
    font.setUnderline(False)
    fm.setFont(font)

    cursor.insertText(text2, fm)

    painter.translate(80, 290)
    doc.drawContents(painter)

    painter.end();
    img.save("text.png")
```

Output:

[image]

You can also use html in QTextDocument:

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    img = QImage(640, 480, QImage.Format_RGB32);
    img.fill(Qt.white);

    text1, text2 ="Stack Overflow".split()
    painter = QPainter(img);

    doc = QTextDocument()
    cursor = QTextCursor(doc)
    cursor.insertHtml("<i><u>{first}</u></i><b><i>{second}<b></i>".format(first=text1, second=text2))

    painter.translate(80, 290)
    doc.drawContents(painter)

    painter.end();
    img.save("text.png")
```

[image]

Comment: Yes this works, but is there anyway to save the file like pdf no like image? i tried something but couldn't make it. After this data are in i am printing the document that is the whole point of it.